# Traffic and Size between Edge and Hub

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Looking for some guidance on what the traffic size and shape is for IoTEdge to Hub communication outside of any module generated messages.

Looking for a baseline on the system traffic outside of the workload traffic for network estimation.

Answer (score 0):

To establish a baseline I would recommend you use IoT Edge Metrics that are built in on both Edge Hub and Edge Agent modules.

> The IoT Edge Hub and Edge Agent module expose a number of metrics in the Prometheus exposition format that provide insights into its operational state.

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/doc/BuiltInMetrics.md